# Bluetooth won't turn on

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I continuously get this same issue. My bluetooth won't be turned on although I can move the switch to do that. I tried several solutions seen here (updating bluez, using `rmmod btusb`, or installing blueman) but those still didn't solve the problem. When I try to run the blueman manager, I get an error saying: `blueman-manager 15.05.02 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting` Does anybody have a clue about that?
[screenshot of bluetooth issue. The bluetooth shall be on (switch above), but won't be started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Pcv.png)

Comment: Look in the app `Additional Drivers` and see if there are any avaliable. Also, please edit your answer with the following details: Are you sure the device has bluetooth? Can you give any information about the adapter (such as a model number)? Did it work in the past?

Comment: lease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.